# Plotting issue with HeatMap in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, heatmap

i want to plot a heatmap in rshiny app. I managed to get it work on r notebook with the correct result. However, when i put the same code into my rshiny app, the heatmap result was different.

[Here is the code in my r shiny notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7jto.png)

Here is the same code inserted in rshiny app:

```
output$heatmapPlot <- renderPlotly({

heat_map_data <- data %>% 
   group_by(year,town,estate_type,flat_type,storey_range) %>% 
  summarise(median_sales = median(resale_price ))

df_matrix <- data.frame(heat_map_data)
print(df_matrix)

ggplot(df_matrix, aes(x = flat_type, y = storey_range, fill = median_sales)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(as.factor(df_matrix$storey_range))))              
})
```

The result in rshinyapp: [Result in rshiny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY7Zf.png)

Can someone pls help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Please have a look at `ggplotly`, a function that converts a `ggplot2::ggplot()` object to a plotly object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please assign `ggplot()` object to `ggplotly()` since you have used `renderPlotly()`.

```
p<- ggplot(....)

p1<- ggplotly(p)

p1
```

Compare the result of print() function before the `ggplot()` function. Contain your data set into reactive function and use it accordingly.